# HP Fortify Warnings

Tags: java, fortify, secure-coding

I am running HP Fortify SCA from ant integrated build and getting the errors/warnings.  I failed miserably to know what's happening and google didn't help much.

1) [warning]: The following references to java symbols could not be resolved. Please make sure to supply all the required jar files that contain these symbols to SCA.
         Notably all these classes are inner classes of source code and two
         methods are from .jar file.  Both source code and .jar are in classpth

2) [error]: Unexpected exception while resolving file
3) [warning]: Unexpected exception while translating file
       For (2) and (3), in the error log Fortify is failing with
       NullPointerException and for some IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: This is not a security question, so is off topic here.

Comment: 1) is a duplicate of [HP Fortify is not able resolve the inner classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40374143/476716).